# Cuepoints in HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am in need of cue points for an HTML5 video player. I found [Cuepoint.js](http://cuepoint.org/) except this is just for things like captions. I need things other than text to change when a cue point is hit.

I sort of made my own cue point logic, but I feel it isn't as efficient as it could be. I am dealing with a small array of times right now which isn't a big deal. I'm afraid when I get into the hundreds it could cause some performance issues.

This is what I came up and it is quite accurate:

```
function timeUpdate(event)
{
    var times = [3,8,13,19,25];
    currentTime = player.currentTime();
    $.each(times,function(key, value)
    {
        if (currentTime >= times[key] && currentTime <= times[key] + 0.3)
        {
            currentIndex++;
            loadAssets(currentIndex);
        }   
    });
}
```

The `times` array is just an example. Is there a more efficient way to do this or is this pretty much it?

Answer (score 1):

Ronnie, You don't need to loop through that array. If the items are in order, just check against the first one, then up the currentIndex by one.

```
function timeUpdate(event)
{
    var times = [3,8,13,19,25];
    currentTime = player.currentTime();

    if (currentTime >= times[currentIndex])
    {
        currentIndex++;
        loadAssets(currentIndex);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is seek function is used?

Comment: Right, until the user rewinds the video. This will only work if controls are disabled.